# Why is an address changing when I add it to an array?

Tags: storage, arrays, memory

I'm encountering a memory / storage issue (I think) w/ an array of addresses where I want to swap out one address with another.

Here's how I've initialized the array:
`address[] public maintainers;`

Here's the function that performs the replacement:

```
  function replaceMaintainer(address _maintainer, address _newMaintainer)
    public
  {
    for (uint i = 0; i < maintainers.length; i++) {
      if (1 == 1) {
          maintainers[i] = _newMaintainer;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

When I test in terminal here's what steps I take:

```
truffle(development)> wallet = MultiSigWallet.at('0x22f79daf3ea53041cbc153e15744b06ee5a12b8a')

truffle(development)> wallet.getMaintainers()
[ '0x65be59ed81a9a5f281e14e1c43d8acbd810aefbf',
  '0x05c390a16112211590f9dafa606612c40aa60bd4',
  '0xe186acfce49f850708a888214345920f32ea0288' ]
```

I should note, the constructor sets up the initial maintainers.

```
truffle(development)> wallet.replaceMaintainer(0xe186acfce49f850708a888214345920f32ea0288, 0xee5c3ec339e01de884f65523b8dfe38b35f90d84)

truffle(development)> wallet.getMaintainers()
[ '0xee5c3ec339e021de43c7c49095748ac100000000',
  '0x05c390a16112211590f9dafa606612c40aa60bd4',
  '0xe186acfce49f850708a888214345920f32ea0288' ]
```

You'll notice the first handful of characters are the same, but the remaining are changed. Any thoughts what's happening here?

This is very much similar to this [MultiSig wallet's `replaceOwner` function](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol). You'll notice I'm using `1 == 1` in the `for` loop. This is because the `_newMaintainer` changes once it's passed to the function.

Comment: Hi there. Can you show us the function that's adding the address to the array, as well as how you're calling it? (Can you also include how you're confirming what's been added to the array?)

Comment: @dougiebuckets Where is the actual function you are using? I don't see it :)

Comment: @JesseBusman I've updated the inquiry w/ the function and additional info. Thanks!

Comment: The odd thing is, the address seems to change when it's passed to the function. I.e., even before I try to replace the existing `_maintainer` address w/ the `_newMaintainer` address

Comment: I'm suspecting the problem is that you need quotation marks around the addresses being passed to `replaceMaintainer()`.